# Haskell / GHCi - loading modules from different directories

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-platform

My haskell application has the following directory structure:

```
src/
    utils/Utils.hs
    subsystem/Subsystem.hs
```

The `Subsystem` module imports `Utils` module. I would like to hand test this code in GHCi.

The problem is GHCi seems to be only looking for modules available in `'.'` (current directory), so I copied `Utils.hs` to subsystem folder and was able to hand-test `Subsytem.hs`. Is there a better way to do this? For example I would like to start GHCi in the `src` directory and let it search for modules in `./utils` and `./subsystem` directories. Can I specify a module path to GHCi?

Comment: `:load dominoes/src/Dominoes.hs` seems to work fine.

Answer (score 23):

You can tell GHCi where to search for modules by using the `-i` option:

```
ghci Foo.Bar -isrc
```

This will load `src/Foo/Bar.hs` into GHCi. This way, you can also specify two different directories like this:

```
ghci Bar.hs -i.:config
```

It will look for the dependencies in ./ and ./config/ .

[See the GHC user's guide for more information about the module search path](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/separate_compilation.html#search-path).

Answer (score 11):

By default, when GHC looks for modules, it interprets `Foo.Bar` as `Foo/Bar.hs`. So if you have a single project, you could have a module `Utils` as `Utils.hs` in the top-level directory, and a module `Utils.Fishcakes` as `Utils/Fishcakes.hs`. Note that `Utils.hs` can exist alongside a directory named `Utils`, or both can exist independently. A common style tends to be using the top-level module to simply re-export things from modules below it in the hierarchy, but this isn't required. The [GHC User Guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/separate-compilation.html) covers the above behavior, as well as describing what other options are supported.

As far as I know, in most cases code will either use the above default structure, will use some other structure specified as part of a cabal build, or will expect to be installed as a library.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to fix the issue by doing the following: under src/ create Utils and Subsystem dirs containing the Utils.hs and Subsystem.hs files which contain the Utils.Utils and Subsystem.Subsystem modules. Then I can run GHCi from src/ and then just do :add Subsystem.Subsystem.

Answer (score 10):

You can create a .ghci file with something like this:

:set -isrc -iutils -isubsystem

Answer (score 4):

If you project looks like the following...

```
src/
    utils/Utils.hs
    subsystem/Subsystem.hs
.....
myproject.cabal
Setup.hs
```

You can create a `.ghci` file in the root directory of the project, same directory that `src`, `myproject.cabal` and `Setup.hs` is in. The content of `.gchi` should be this..

```
:set -isrc/utils -isrc/subsystem
```

Now you can call ghci from the root directory of your project and it will auto-load any linked modules.

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude>:load src/subsystem/Subsystem.hs
... should load Subsystem.hs
```